# Merge one folder onto another but keep diff (non-existing) files

Tags: command-line, cp, merge

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
Folder-A
    File-1
    File-2
    File-4
    Folder-A-1
        File-5
        File-6
    Folder-A-2
        File-7

Folder-B
    File-1
    File-2
    File-3
    Folder-A-1
        File-5
```

I want to copy `Folder-A` onto / on top of `Folder-B` so that, logically, the result is this:

```
Folder-B
    File-1 *
    File-2 *
    File-3
    File-4 +
    Folder-A-1
        File-5 *
        File-6 +
    Folder-A-2 +
        File-7 +
```

Where `*` is an overwrite and `+` is an addition.

In other words, recursively, if the file (or folder) exists in the same path, overwrite it, and if it's new, add it.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

That's the default behavior of `cp`. So all you need to do is a regular recursive `cp`:

```
cp -r Folder-A/* Folder-B/
```

---

To demonstrate:

```
$ tree
.
├── Folder-A
│   ├── File-1
│   ├── File-2
│   ├── File-4
│   ├── Folder-A-1
│   │   ├── File-5
│   │   └── File-6
│   └── Folder-A-2
│       └── File-7
└── Folder-B
    ├── File-1
    ├── File-2
    ├── File-3
    └── Folder-A-1
        └── File-5

$ cp -r Folder-A/* Folder-B
$ tree
.
├── Folder-A
│   ├── File-1
│   ├── File-2
│   ├── File-4
│   ├── Folder-A-1
│   │   ├── File-5
│   │   └── File-6
│   └── Folder-A-2
│       └── File-7
└── Folder-B
    ├── File-1
    ├── File-2
    ├── File-3
    ├── File-4
    ├── Folder-A-1
    │   ├── File-5
    │   └── File-6
    └── Folder-A-2
        └── File-7
```